# What does the term "perturb" mean?

Tags: terminology, calculus-of-variations

I've been studying Calculus of Variations and I came a cross with the term "perturb" in my study material, but the term was not defined. The sentence where I read it from was:

> "Rigid extremals are extremals that cannot be perturbed, and still
>   satisfy the constraint."

The material also uses the sentence:

> "Perturbing around a curve"...?

What does this mean? Thank you.

P.S. Could you please post your answer as an answer and not as comment so that I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my dictionary

**Peturb**

1. To disturb greatly in mind; disquiet
2. To throw in confusion; disorder
3. To cause (a moving body, celestial object, etc.) to deviate from a theoretically (orbital) motion.

I think we can ignore the first definition here but the other two are relevant .  If you were to nudge a system slightly you are perturbing it and we may want to  consider more stable if a small perturbation dies down and returns to a steady state quickly than a system which takes a long time to recover or one which never recovers.

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)